# After installing nvidia drivers, many graphical applications won't launch

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 17.04 on a Dell Inspiron 7559 (skylake i5 and gtx 960m)

After installing Nvidia drivers, Steam and OBS (so far) won't launch and I get this errors:

- Steam:

  ```
  Steam Error OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display
  ```
- OBS:

  ```
  Failed to initialize video. Your GPU may not be supported,
  or your graphics drivers may need to be updated.
  ```

[image: (screenshot)]

In additional drivers, it says that I'm using the nvidia drivers:

[image: screenshot]

However, I'm not sure why I got 3 different nvidia drivers available, 375, 378 and 381. I've must have installed them wrong. I did tried to install them several times,

However the output of `lspci  | grep VGA"` says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

It seems that I'm  using intel GPU. 
My Nvidia gpu works, I've used it under Windows, also `lspci | grep NVIDIA` says `02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)` so it is recognized.

Is bumblebee still necessary? What can I do? , I've  tried `sudo apt purge nvidia*` and then reinstalled with `sudo apt install nvidia-current`  but nothing different happened

EDIT: Secure Boot was disabled since I installed Ubuntu Mate and still is.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Changing to proprietary driver after disabling secure boot worked for me. I don't know anything about your exact issue though