# Kubuntu 16.04 system crash regularly

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, dell, crash, xps

For a couple of weeks my kubuntu install crashes regularly. Everything completely freezes. No mouse cursor moment, nothing. Most of the time that it happens my machine is running a heavy node task. Than 1 of the 4 core's is at 100%.

I have tried numerus different kernels but this does not seem to have any effect.

$ uname -r
4.11.4-041104-generic

My bios version is: 1.4.17

Here is a system log when it happend: (in this case it happend when playing a youtube video)

```
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078006] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078041] Modules linked in: asix usbnet mii bnep pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_multitouch i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core dell_wmi nls_iso8859_1 dell_laptop intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_led dell_smbios dcdbas snd_soc_skl snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_match snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_usb_audio coretemp snd_usbmidi_lib kvm_intel snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm snd_rawmidi irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_seq uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core aesni_intel
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078423]  videodev aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd media intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer input_leds snd joydev serio_raw soundcore brcmfmac rtsx_pci_ms memstick brcmutil cfg80211 mei_me shpchp mei idma64 virt_dma processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_lpss_pci intel_pch_thermal hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth int3403_thermal intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss intel_hid int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal sparse_keymap acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid acpi_pad acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc sunrpc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper nvme syscopyarea sysfillrect nvme_core rtsx_pci psmouse sysimgblt ahci fb_sys_fops drm libahci wmi i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078799] CPU: 2 PID: 1422 Comm: kwin_x11 Tainted: G           OE   4.11.4-041104-generic #201706071003
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078849] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9350/07TYC2, BIOS 1.4.17 05/10/2017
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078887] task: ffff8f86ef4dae00 task.stack: ffffb61d41e9c000
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078948] RIP: 0010:gen8_ppgtt_insert_pte_entries.isra.43+0xc7/0x1a0 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.078986] RSP: 0000:ffffb61d41e9f9f0 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079012] RAX: 00000000354d0000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079041] RDX: 0000000000000018 RSI: ffe41dcbd33a0000 RDI: 00000000354d001b
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079071] RBP: ffffb61d41e9fa48 R08: ffe41dcbd33a0590 R09: ffffffffc042e07a
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079105] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: dead000000000100 R12: 00000000000000b3
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079142] R13: ffffb61d41e9fa60 R14: ffe41dcbd33a0000 R15: 00000000000001d8
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079176] FS:  00007eff19455940(0000) GS:ffff8f86fed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079212] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079241] CR2: 00005591209a3938 CR3: 000000026ec1b000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079270] Call Trace:
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079310]  gen8_ppgtt_insert_entries+0xad/0x120 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079354]  ppgtt_bind_vma+0x40/0x50 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079398]  i915_vma_bind+0xa0/0x170 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079444]  __i915_vma_do_pin+0x30b/0x3b0 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079490]  i915_gem_execbuffer_reserve_vma.isra.30+0x14d/0x1b0 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079545]  i915_gem_execbuffer_reserve.isra.31+0x3c5/0x3f0 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079601]  i915_gem_do_execbuffer.isra.37+0x4af/0x15b0 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079637]  ? __switch_to+0x23c/0x520
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079662]  ? __schedule+0x3ce/0x8c0
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079685]  ? schedule+0x36/0x80
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079706]  ? futex_wait_queue_me+0xd3/0x120
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079753]  i915_gem_execbuffer2+0xa1/0x1e0 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079794]  drm_ioctl+0x218/0x4b0 [drm]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079837]  ? i915_gem_execbuffer+0x310/0x310 [i915]
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079866]  ? do_futex+0x104/0x520
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079888]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa3/0x600
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079911]  ? __schedule+0x3ce/0x8c0
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079932]  ? SyS_futex+0x83/0x180
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079952]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079970]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.079996] RIP: 0033:0x7eff18f4af07
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080017] RSP: 002b:00007ffccb25ec38 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080058] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000001bcf030 RCX: 00007eff18f4af07
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080094] RDX: 00007ffccb25ec80 RSI: 0000000040406469 RDI: 000000000000000f
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080131] RBP: 00007eff194245a0 R08: 0000000001d05ce0 R09: 0000000000000000
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080174] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007eff0f4e9b50
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080212] R13: 0000000002424717 R14: 00007ffccb25f050 R15: 0000000000d83170
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080250] Code: 8b 45 08 c1 e0 0c 48 03 47 10 48 89 c7 48 83 cf 1b 85 db 74 12 48 89 c7 48 83 c8 13 40 80 cf 83 83 fb 03 48 0f 44 f8 41 83 c4 01 <49> 89 38 41 81 fc 00 02 00 00 74 78 4c 89 ef e8 c5 a0 e2 e2 84 
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.080413] RIP: gen8_ppgtt_insert_pte_entries.isra.43+0xc7/0x1a0 [i915] RSP: ffffb61d41e9f9f0
Jun 20 18:51:46 billy-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [11616.088989] ---[ end trace b0c9a8b8724703bb ]---
```

Here is some additional info:

```
OpenGL vendor string:  Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string:Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 OpenGL shading language v: 1.30
Driver:                Intel
GPU class:             Unknown
OpenGL version:        3.0
GLSL version:          1.30
Mesa version:          12.0.6
X server version:      1.18.4
Linux kernel version:  4.11.4
Requires strict binding:yes
GLSL shaders:          yes
Texture NPOT support:  yes
Virtual Machine:       no
```

Any ideas?

Kind regards,
Billy

Comment: Probably report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It appeared to be a kernel problem. 
After installing: 4.11.11-041111-generic all was good. 
Have been running it for 2 months, no more crashes. ;-)

Thx Javier for you help!

regards,
Billy

Answer (score 0):

For sure you have a problem with the video driver.

Try the image for ubuntu 14.04 from dell support

If the problem persist in 14.04 maybe hot?
Your model is xps 13 9350?

I see that isn't new installation don't load 14.04. maybe when upgrade the driver the system start to freeze.

then try to change propietary driver.

[After installing nvidia drivers, many graphical applications won't launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926900/after-installing-nvidia-drivers-many-graphical-applications-wont-launch)

done?

Comment: Thx for your answer! Yes it's a xps 13 9350. I have been running kubuntu on it since late 2015. Have not had a problem like this before. It's my work laptop. I have to have it up and running every day. I don't know if i can use that image. because i have my home dir on a separate partition. Can i still use that image than? And not lose my data?

Comment: I added some video driver info to my post. Is there a way to rollback  a video driver?